# How to remove "Did You Mean:" from Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I don't know much more about SEO, but it's interesting to learn about it. When I tried to search my website with an associated keyword or you can say with the exact name of the domain, I got some suggestions by Google. Here's [the search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=webomnizz&oq=webomnizz&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0i13l9.461699.463985.0.464509.9.9.0.0.0.0.257.1133.4j3j2.9.0....0...1c.1.28.hp..3.6.439.Mx35LQAdJ6E).

First of all, I don't want to spamming here, I just want prove my question and want to give a hint about what I am talking here. The above link display the *Did You Mean*, I know the specific reason why Google shows this, but I want to know the Google's guidelines and some guidance by you experts so that if someone search for the particular keyword then Google hide that *Did You Mean* and display the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you certainly know, Google displays *Did you mean* because Google considers there are no results to display for this keyword (*webomnizz*).

However, there is a solution to solve this. You just need to speak about your brand (*webomnizz*) over the web by creating webpages on various websites and on Facebook, Google+ etc. Google will find and index all these webpages about your brand and could return results for this keyword search.

For example, Google already index your [profile webpage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/12534/webomnizz) of Pro Webmasters. It's a good indicator for Google to specify your keyword (or your brand) exists. Keep going.

Comment: **creating webpages on various websites** do you mean creating back-links?

Comment: No, you need to create something indexed by Google (mostly webpages) which speak about your brand (your keyword). Google needs to find your keywords in webpages over the web to understand this keyword exists.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion and i know it takes long time to show the result.

Comment: You need to be patient with Google, you have no choice. Good luck.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Google shows "Did you mean" even when there are results, but it thinks they aren't the ones that you want.  There are lots of documents that use mis-spellings that Google will actually show to you, but still shows "did you mean" for that mis-spelling.    As you suggest, strengthening your brand is the correct solution.

Comment: +1 for the answer and I can provide further proof. When our company SOFTKUBE started, we used to always get this with Google trying to correct it as cube with a C instead of a K. A few profiles on social networks (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, and LinkedIn, at least!) using the username SOFTKUBE and a few blog posts fixed this in a matter of weeks. Good luck. Try searching for SOFTKUBE now in Google and see the nice and organized listings that you get ;)