# Searching google for our domain name shows only another site whose domain differs by dashes

Tags: seo, domains, google-search

I need a website to have good results when searching Google for the exact domain name.

The domain name is `le-petit-pois.fr`, but when looking for this phrase in Google, only the website `lepetitpois.fr` can be seen on the search result.
`lepetitpois.fr` is an older website, not related to `le-petit-pois.fr`.

There is an other domain name, `le-fraisier.fr`, which is only a redirection to `le-petit-pois.fr`. When searched for on Google, it is the first result.

Why doesn't the website shows up when searching for the domain and what solution other than putting more value to the domain name in the SEO would be valuable?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! The best solution is time, content, and engagement on the site and using social media. If you are a business, register your business using Google My Business. Also look for quality inbound linking opportunities. Do not set up junk links nor go for the hard to get links. New sites do not rank well. It will take time. Months in fact. Popularity is another factor. As you engage people on your site, using links, and with social media, your site will begin to rank higher in the SERPs for the searches you should have. Cheers!!

Comment: The solution to this issue is likely that you need to work on your SEO.  Why are you precluding that solution?

Comment: Related: [How to remove “Did You Mean:” from Google Search?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54084/how-to-remove-did-you-mean-from-google-search) and [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm not putting aside the SEO as I'm still working on it in order to make the domain name a primary focus.

For the websites I've been working on in the past, searching for the domain name always returned the website, even when newly indexed by Google. I can't get my head around why this one is not working.