# Google Search and YouTube search change spelling to spelling with zero results

Tags: seo, google, google-search, youtube, spelling

NOTE: [How to remove "Did You Mean:" from Google Search?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54084/how-to-remove-did-you-mean-from-google-search)
does not answer this question. The suggested fixes in this question is to set up FB, IG, and other social media pages. We have had these for months. We have 576 Instagram followers, 293 followers on Facebook, 17,425 views on Vimeo, Youtube, Pinterest and LinkedIn presence. Here is the response in a YouTube search:

[image]

Let's be clear. If you search for my company name and product name YT changes the spelling to something that doesn't exist and suggests a video with no matching result terms (using either spelling) disparaging OTHER luxury handbags, while leaving the viewer with the impression it is referring to our handbags.

**Google**

When a user searches for our business, [`Aslaen Vaugn`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=aslaen%20vaugn), Google changes the spelling to `Aslan Vaughn` and displays these results:

[image]

If you misspell part of the name (aslan vaugn or aslaen vaughn), it shows my company at the top of the results. For the first few months it just seemed like it was taking some time to percolate, but over 7 months we have had 17,500 unique visitors and 90 backlinks.

[image]

The only results for `Aslan Vaugn` is the birth announcement of the second child of a musician in New Jersey. It is a Facebook post and has 14 likes. Google is favoring a spelling that has only two results with 14+ views over my company with dozens of results and tens of thousands of views.

How is this possible? An FB post with 14 likes is that much more popular than a business with 17,500 unique visitors and 40,000 page views (despite the Google obfuscation)? Do I have an enemy at Google? On other search engines my company covers the first few pages in results. Through Google, you cannot find our company no matter how many pages in you go. Unless you search for the term in quotes, [`"aslaen vaugn"`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=aslaen+vaugn&nfpr=1). In which case we cover the first few pages here like in the other search engines:

[image]

Comment: The other question is the same regardless of whether the answers are great.   If you need to call attention to it to get better answers, I'd recommend creating a bounty for it.

Comment: Your first question is in the re-open queue so that our users can decide if it deserves to be reopened.  I've recused myself from the process since your edit doesn't differentiate the question from the original IMO and I'm the one who closed the question.   It is spammy to ask the same question a second time to try to get around a closed question, so please don't do that.

Comment: The notice said specifically to open a new question. "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: Can I put a bounty on a closed question?

Comment: There have been some (imo) thorough and high-quality answers on your question already - especially ICap's answer - with some discussion clarifying things in comments. I can see that you haven't fully implemented all of ICap's recommendations, especially linking social media from the website's footer which is low hanging fruit. What part of your question, exactly, remains unresolved?

Comment: I have been implementing every suggestion as they have come up from both StackExchange and other developers. Nothing has changed anything. So far as I can tell I have implemented everything suggested that can be done without spending tens of thousands of dollars and getting away from Shopify - which is ridiculous. The suggestion that Shopify will not do better SEO than I can is unreasonable. I am on Google Merchant, but none of my products show up in Shopping searches either. These issues are unique to Google. All Google systems are affected and no other systems are affected (Bing, Yandex, etc

Comment: I have changed the GMB and my company now shows up if you search for terms OTHER than my company's name, like "Aslan Vaugn" or "Aslaen Vaughn". But still nothing if you search for the correct spelling of my company's name, "Aslaen Vaugn". As far as being more well known, that's a chicken and egg thing, isn't it? If 40,000 page views and 17,500 video views is "unknown" I don't know how to react. I have been a web developer for 25 years now and this site has more traffic than all but one of the sites I built (an app that deals with 10,000 trx per second).

Comment: ... make that a max of 10,000 per minute.

Comment: @Maximillian Laumeister if you can re-open the question I can answer with my solution: I changed the home page title from "Aslaen Vaugn" to "Aslaen Vaugn - Aslan Vaughn". I also changed the alt text of the logos (also the H1 tag) from "Aslaen Vaugn" to "Aslan Vaughn". It took about 12 hours and is now the first result in Google searches.

Comment: @orbitingeden Glad you were able to find some success! Technically it may be a dupe, but I added a re-open vote anyways since your Q&A is so much higher quality than the one it was closed as a dupe of.

Comment: The original question was reopened so that you can add your answer, per @MaximillianLaumeister suggestion. In the future, if a question is closed, try to edit that question to address those issues so that it can be reopened, versus asking the same question twice. If you don't understand the reasons why it was closed, you can ask for clarification on our Meta site.