# Prevent Google Chrome for suggesting my site as a lookalike URL of some other legitimate site

Tags: domains, google-chrome

Google Chrome is now [warning users when the visit domains that look like a typo for some other domain](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-chrome-to-warn-users-about-impostor-sites-with-lookalike-urls/290621/). They call this feature "Navigation suggestions for lookalike URLs"

[image: did you mean message in Chrome]

However, sometimes the suggestions aren't correct. Let's say I administer the site `xyz.example`. I was made aware that visitors to a different site with a similar domain, let's say `zyx.example`, were asked by Chrome whether they want to be redirected to my site. Because of the nature of the domain name, this could affect many sites which are not mimicking my site. This has caused visitors to those sites to be confused and use our contact details to try to contact the other party, which wastes time and benefits no one.

Is there procedure where I, as the owner of the site that Chrome thinks is being mimicked, can whitelist individual sites or tell Google/Chrome to not issue this warning for the "benefit" my domain altogether? I have access Google Search Console for the domain in question.

Comment: From the perspective of the other site: [How to remove "Did You Mean:" from Google Search?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54084/how-to-remove-did-you-mean-from-google-search)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's a different feature, where Google does a fuzzy search because it thinks there are too few results for a certain keyword. What I'm asking about is presented to the user as a security feature, which has a very different impact on how it's perceived.

Comment: I've made some edits to make it clearer that they are two different things.

Comment: How to disable this feature in your own browser: [Chrome "Did you mean to go to" banner](https://superuser.com/questions/1583759/chrome-did-you-mean-to-go-to-banner)